# React iterate nested arrays/objects with map. Is return mandatory to render each map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

I'm new to React.
I'm building a small function component that renders the weaknesses of a Pokemon.

It takes the type of the Pokemon stored in the state (pokemonState.types) as an array of objects for each type, compare the type to a JSON file containing all the type effectiveness (see below).

**types_data.json**

```
  "electric": {
"attack": {
  "double": ["flying", "water"],
  "half": ["dragon", "electric", "grass"],
  "zero": ["ground"]
},
"defense": {
  "half": ["electric", "flying", "steel"],
  "double": ["ground"],
  "zero": []
}
```

To get the data I want, I need to do several iterations and I noticed my component only renders when I specify the return keyword and wrap my element in a HTML tag.

**Function that doesn't render anything (but console.log doesn't return undefined)**

```
  const pokemonTypeChart = () => {
if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonState)) {
  const allTypes = Object.entries(types_data);
  const typeEffectiveness = allTypes.map(([key, value]) => {
    pokemonState.types.map((el) => {
      if (el.type.name === key) {
        console.log(key, value);
        return <p>{el}</p>;
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <p>{typeEffectiveness}</p>
    </div>
  );
}};
```

**Function that works well:**

```
const pokemonTypeChart = () => {
if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonState)) {
  const allTypes = Object.entries(types_data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Type Effectiveness</h1>
      {allTypes.map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          <>
            {pokemonState.types.map((el, i) => {
              if (el.type.name === key)
                return <h3 key={i}>{value.defense.double}</h3>;
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}};
```

**My question are:**

- For the function that doesn't render anything, the problem is that I don't use return after each iteration right?
- Is my second function good practice in this scenario? is there a cleaner way I should I have wrote it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My daughter is 6 years old & we spend a ton of time together playing pokemon, so I thought I'd take a little extra time tonight to help you work through your issues here. Hope you find it helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your first function isn't working is that you are returning `<p>{el}</p>`.

`el` is equal to an object & you are expecting a string.

Specifically, in this case, it is something like `{type:{name: "electric"}`

If you change that line from `return <p>{el}</p>;` to `return <p>{el.type.name}</p>;`, then that fixes our inner `.map`, so you are getting closer.

However, you've also got a second problem... the outer `.map` function is not returning anything. Your `typeEffectiveness` variable is what we're ultimately rendering, and that variable is equal to the result from calling `allTypes.map`. While your nested `pokemonState.types.map` function is getting returned to the parent `.map` function, your parent `.map` function does not have a return statement.

Ultimately, you are rendering `{typeEffectiveness}`, so we've gotta make sure that variable is an array of react elements that will render to the DOM.

There were a couple other minor issues as well. Namely, we have to remove the paragraph tags  `<p>{typeEffectiveness}</p>` here or we'd end up with nested `p` tags, since each item in the `typeEffectiveness` list is already enclosed in `<p></p>`.

Finally, you should add key tags to your list items as well.                     `<p key="{el.type.name}">{el.type.name}</p>`

Dig into the documentation on Lists & Keys here:  https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

The following code is a debugged version of your first function.

I also included a refactored version of your section function below. It would be fairly inefficient to map through the entire `types_data` object entries, when we really only care about the types present in our `pokemonState`, so take a look at my approach to that below as well.

```js
const e = React.createElement;

const pokemonState ={types: [{type:{name: "electric"}}]};
let types_data = {
    "electric": {
        "attack": {
            "double": ["flying", "water"],
            "half": ["dragon", "electric", "grass"],
            "zero": ["ground"]
        },
        "defense": {
            "half": ["electric", "flying", "steel"],
            "double": ["ground"],
            "zero": []
        }
    }
};


const PokemonTypeChart = () => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonState)) {
        const allTypes = Object.entries(types_data);
        const typeEffectiveness = allTypes.map(([key, value]) => {
            return (pokemonState.types.map((el) => {
                if (el.type.name === key) {
                    return (
                    <p key="{el.type.name}">{el.type.name}</p>
                    );
                    
                }
            }));
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>
                {typeEffectiveness}
            </div>
        );
    }};




const domContainer = document.querySelector('#pokemon');
ReactDOM.render(e(PokemonTypeChart), domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="pokemon"></div>
```

```js
const e = React.createElement;

const pokemonState ={types: [{type:{name: "electric"}}]};
let types_data = {
    "electric": {
        "attack": {
            "double": ["flying", "water"],
            "half": ["dragon", "electric", "grass"],
            "zero": ["ground"]
        },
        "defense": {
            "half": ["electric", "flying", "steel"],
            "double": ["ground"],
            "zero": []
        }
    }
};


const PokemonChart = () => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonState)) {
        const plistItems = pokemonState.types.map((item) => 
            types_data[item.type.name].defense.double.map((i) => 
                <p key={i}>{i}</p>
            ));
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Type Effectiveness</h1>
                {plistItems}
            </div>
        );
    }};
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#pokemon');
ReactDOM.render(e(PokemonChart), domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="pokemon"></div>
```

Comment: @FriedrichGLX Glad you found it helpful! Be sure to come back and let me know when the finished product is live :)